# virtual function calls in constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-destructor

```
    class Base
    {
    public:
        Base(){Foo();}
        ~Base(){Foo();}
        virtual void Foo(){std::cout<<"base";}
    };

    class Derived: public Base
    {
    public:
        Derived(){Foo();}
        ~Derived(){Foo();}
        void Foo(){std::cout<<"derived";}
    };

      //main
     {
         Derived d;
     }
```

Any idea why this code prints out "base" and "derived"?
I understand the advice is not to put virtual function calls inside constructor or desctructor, I just want to know why the above code would have the behaviour. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it outputs "basederivedderivedbase" (after fixing `//main`), and if you think about it for awhile, you'll see why.

Answer (score 4):

During execution of the constructor of a class `C`, the derived subobjects are not, yet, constructed. Thus, the dynamic type of the object under construction is the static type of the constructor, i.e., `C`. Any `virtual` function will be dispatched as if the object is type `C`. Likewise, when an object of a derived type is destroyed and the destructor of `C` is being run, all the derived subobjects are already destroyed and, again, the type behaves as if it is of type `C`.

That is, during construction and destruction the type of an object involving inheritance changes! The dynamic dispatch is arranged to match the current type of the object.